# listings: using Python and Matlab code

Tags: listings

Can I `\lstset` to define both Matlab code and Python code? or will last one override the first one? or does `listings` know the difference when there is a `.m` or `.py` extension and use the correct `\lstset`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption={Some Python code}]
class example(object):
    pass
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Matlab, caption={Some Matlab code}]
function [y1, y2] = funfun(x1, x2)
    disp(x1)
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Or you can `\lstset` the language before the listing.